Java from start of path not being executed
There is a Java 1.8 installed on our Windows Server 2022 Datacenter, version 21H2.  I've downloaded Java 17 for some of my own work and then manually set the PATH environment variable with Java 17's bin directory at the front (see the screen shot).  However, when I execute java -version from the command line, I get the Java 1.8 version, which is later in the path.  Why is it running Java 1.8?  If I explicitly running Java 17 using the full path to java.exe from the root, it runs as expected, telling me the version number is 17.
In addition my JAVA_HOME variable points to 17:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\kcassell\Tools\Java\jdk-17.0.12



Have you set JAVA_HOME?

Yes, JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\kcassell\Tools\Java\jdk-17.0.12.  I've updated the question to say so.

Your path is wrong - you have bin:C: instead of bin;C: :)

Yeah, I just noticed.  D'oh.  If you post that as an answer, I'll delete my answer and give you credit.

Answered ......

Java from start of path not being executed
After carefully examining your PATH I can see that the first entry is terminated with a colon : instead of a semi-colon ;.
Fixing this will resolve your issue (not tested).
